# Pagination Not Visible on Magento on Mobile devices

Tags: magento, mobile, pagination

Using Magento, items from our store do not paginate on iphone/ipad. When you are on the website on iphone, it only shows a handful of items with no option to go to the next page of items. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Could you add more details, screenshots etc?

Comment: Sure, thanks... If you click the link below, and go to clothing under the menu... when you scroll down it only shows you a limited number of items. There is no links to go to the next page of items....http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://tajbysabrina.com